# Using PHP inside HTML

Tags: php, html

I would like to know how can i use variable here instead of constant. for ex
I have this statement

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/abc.css')?>"/>
```

Now Instead of abc.css , I want tomake it variable instead of hardcode value
like `$A = "abc.css" ;`
So statement should look like ==>

```
$A = "abc.css" ;
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/$A')?>"/>
```

Please guide me, I'm not able to do it.

Comment: Learn to accept correct answers, then learn the very basics of PHP, take the baby steps, then come back on a programming forum.

Comment: @mario: all right. noted for further comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only code between `<?php` and `?>` marks is considered and processed as PHP code. And you placed `$A = "abc.css" ;` outside these marks. So the code in `<link>` tag is trying to work with undeclared variable.

Also, only variables in [double quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) are replaced.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php $A = "abc.css" ; ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("css/$A")?>"/>
```

Variables within **double quoted** strings are replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
<?php $A = "abc.css" ; ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/'.$A)?>"/>
```